# Google Colab recently raise error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud.storage.retry'

Tags: pytorch, google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory, allennlp

My code just worked properly on local and colab, however recently faced the following error on colab.
I use google colab to run my code.
The allennlp package was installed.

[Error when run code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxDT5.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
2. restart runtime

The above command solved the issue for me!

Comment: You answer helped me, thank you.